# go pg #42P01 invalid reference to FROM-clause

Tags: postgresql, go, pg

i am trying to do a left join on query but i have an invalid reference to FROM-Clause
here are the structure of the code

this is the product table

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    productdesc TEXT,
    costprice DOUBLE PRECISION,
    recommendprice DOUBLE PRECISION,
    views BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
    enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,

    category_id BIGINT REFERENCES categories (id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,

)
```

this is the category table

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
    id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    pid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    image VARCHAR(255),

);
```

this is the type struct

```
type Product struct {
    TableName struct{} `sql:"products"`
    ID          int64  `json:"id"`
    TITLE string `json:"title"`
    PRODUCTDESC string `json:"product_desc"`
    COSTPRICE float64 `json:"costprice"`
    RECOMMENDPRICE float64 `json:"recommendprice"`
    VIEWS int64 `json:"views"`
    ENABLED bool `json:"enabled"`
    CATEGORYNAME string `json:"categoryname"`
}
type Category struct {
     tableName struct{} `pg:"categories"`
    ID      int64  `json:"id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Image   string `json:"image"`
}
```

this is the actual query to database

```
func (t *ProductRepo) GetAllProducts() ([]*domain.Product, error) {
    var products []*domain.Product
    query := t.DB.Model(&products).
        ColumnExpr("products.*").
        ColumnExpr("c.id AS category_id, c.title AS categoryname").
        Join("LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = products.category_id")

    err := query.Select()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return products, nil
}
```

this is the actual error from postman

```
{
    "error": "ERROR #42P01 invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \"products\""
}
```

any help would be great,

thanks advance

Jason

Comment: Can you add sufficient code in the actual query block so that your imports are clear?

Comment: What is generated query text?

Comment: How do I get the.generated text?